# What PDF should be fit to a rank histogram?

Tags: distributions, ranking, histogram, discrete-data

A Rank Histogram (or Talagrand Diagram) is a neat way of measuring whether your numerical model is giving appropriate variance. It's used for weather and climate forcasting, where you only have one observational series, and many model series (an ensemble). It's [described pretty clearly here](http://www.eumetcal.org/resources/ukmeteocal/verification/www/english/msg/ver_prob_forec/uos4b/uos4b_ko1.htm). Basically, you take a handful of runs of your model, then for each timestep/gridpoint, whatever, you calculate how the observations rank relative to the model ensemble. Then you plot a histogram of those ranks. If the histogram is u-shaped, then variance is too low (obs are rank high or low too often), if the histogram looks kind of gaussian, then the variance is too high (obs rarely ranks high or low), and if the histogram is flat, then your variance is spot-on (obs have a similar variance as the ensemble).

Examples from http://www.eumetcal.org/resources/ukmeteocal/temp/msgcal/www/english/msg/ver_prob_forec/uos4b/uos4b_ko1.htm:

[image: Example rank histograms]

So the question is, **which distribution** should I fit to this kind of data, and **why**? The latter part of the question is more important, because I *think* that the correct distribution is [the Beta-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution), but I'm unfamiliar with this area.

Comment: The only possible correct answer to this question as *generally* posed is "practically any distribution." This is because the diagram is a tool to compare two *arbitrary* distributions: "observations" and the "model ensemble." They could differ in literally any fashion. By asking such a question, then, you appear to presuppose some kind of connection between the model and the observations. This is a fair assumption, but the nature of the connection depends on the kind of model and what it models. So: what kind of model and what kinds of observations do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber, (I'm assuming you're referring to the note at the end): right, I should have said data set *types*. ie. ordinal/continuous, finite/infinite domain, etc. And more specifically, data types like ranks, odds, what ever. But I guess the answer is "practically any [ordinal, finite domain] distribution", so maybe I'm better off removing that part of the question.

Comment: @Whuber: I kind of assumed the latter part of your comment was covered in the question. Because I'm looking at weather/climate models, there is of course a strong connection between observations and models: theoretical fluid dynamics, radiative convection, etc.

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11876/fitting-a-beta-binomial-model-in-the-case-of-overdispersion-in-r

Comment: What leads you to think that the 'correct distribution would be beta-binomial'? I see nothing that really suggests it couldn't in practice be almost anything. The examples shown might be more-or-less described by a flexible discrete distribution like a beta-binomial but that doesn't make them beta-binomial. No doubt you could make an argument that would imply a beta-binomial, though I think I don't know enough about the whole area to judge whether it's tenable.

Comment: @Glen_b: Basically I thought that because it's discrete data over a finite interval, and the graphs look similar. I don't have any better rationale, but that's kind of what I was trying to get at with the question I guess: is there a reason to assume that this data is NOT from a close-to-beta-binomial distribution?

Comment: If you're just looking for something that might be a reasonable model, it seems okay to use it, but what's to stop it from being something very different some of the time. Note that a lack of evidence *against* a particular hypothesis is not of itself a reason to think it's the case; if your main aim is to get a decent description of the distribution then as long as you do some reasonableness checks (the above plots, if they cover the range of results, may be sufficient) I see no particular issue. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... On the other hand if you want more than just "these sort of fit the data", you would need to produce (for example) an argument that you had something that should produce some good approximation of a beta mix of binomials (and I can think of a rough outline of such an argument but I am not in a position to address its reasonableness in this context).

Comment: @Glen_b: I'm looking for the argument, not the description.

Comment: Oh, okay. That wasn't clear. As I said the circumstances aren't sufficient for me to know whether the sorts of arguments one might make are tenable, but (for example) it could come from making an argument than if (something) were held constant, there'd be a situation akin to bernoulli trials, but that thing varies. You'd then argue that the varying thing should vary $p$ in those bernoulli trials. Now if the $p$ was roughly beta (and it may be possible also to give an argument for that), you would then use a beta-binomial for the mix. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ...  An alternative argument might start with the beta and use say a series expansion around it which values are then ranked and then try to argue that the beta-binomial is an approximation to the resulting process (such an argument would be harder to make the details work for, obviously). Or there might be other ways to argue it.

Comment: @Glen_b: Can you see a way to resolve this question? I'm happy to provide more specifics of the circumstances, if that would help. I feel like the climate context combined with the rank histogram methodology already provide pretty tight constraints, and it's more a matter of translating from non-stats-trained-science-speak into stats land and back again. Let me know if I can provide more info or narrow down the question (ideally without making it useless to others who might come along). An answer that just states the requirements for me to be able to answer the question myself would also work.

Comment: @naught101 It's not clear to me that one can justify *any* particular choice in general; almost any flexible continuous\*  family of distributions should suffice, but I am thinking that it might make more sense to look at a set of orthogonal polynomials (in this case with respect to the uniform weight function), taken to say order 4 or 6 or thereabouts. \*(I say continuous because the actual distribution is continuous and the binning is quite arbitrary). One can always discretize at the end.

Comment: @Glen_b: they're ranks. The number of bins (actually values) is the number of members in the ensemble + 1. I don't think that's arbitrary. The obs can't have a rank of 1.5.

Comment: The supposition that this may be a beta-binomial distribution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) may be correct. However, that is not what would be used for hypothesis testing, which would be to quantify the goodness of fit to a uniform distribution, for example using chi-squared test for categorical data [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test), as suggested [here](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/people/tom.hamill/rankh_mwr.pdf).