# Rank histogram (or Talagrand Diagram) of precipitation data

Tags: ranking, histogram

Given a dataset of lines containing 6 wind **forecast** values plus 1 observed (actual) value in each like:

```
 FCT1   FCT2     FCT3   FCT4   FCT5     FCT6   OBSERVED
-3.17   3.51    -5.71   1.37   -0.22   -0.65    -2.38   
-2.7    2.21    -0.71   2.73   -0.33   -2.62    -1.38   
-1.2    3.15    -4.17   3.33   -0.48   -1.65    -2.30   
...
-3.0    3.50    -1.79   3.37   -0.18   -0.62    -2.32
```

To make a rank histogram (or [Talagrand Diagram](http://www.eumetcal.org/resources/ukmeteocal/verification/www/english/msg/ver_prob_forec/uos4b/uos4b_ko1.htm)), I understand that I need to loop through the lines, sort the **forecast** values for each one and assume that the ordered values (six, in this case) are the inner limits of each bin on the diagram. 6 limits generates 7 bins. Then, I need to take the corresponding **observed** value and increase the bin it fits (the bin that its range contains the observed value). I need to do it for every row, so each row has its limits. It has to do with [What PDF should be fit to a rank histogram?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32370/what-pdf-should-be-fit-to-a-rank-histogram). I think it is not a simple histogram built via `hist()` in R. Am I wrong?

> [image]

How about a precipitation **forecast** data? Like:

```
 FCT1   FCT2   FCT3   FCT4   FCT5   FCT6   OBSERVED
  0       0     0.1    0     0        0        0
  0       0     0      0     0.02     0        0
  0       0.1   0      0     0        0        3
```

What am I supposed to do to know the bin that has the range that fits the **observed** value like 0, for example? How can I build 7 bins from this **forecast** data?

Comment: Tkx @gung, text was edited to clarify my doubt.

Comment: I've got the answer from http://test.scs.fsu.edu/presentations/wkshp_Mar2006allgood_rev.pdf: **"When two or more forecasts have same value (most commonly 0), random selection is made for which bin receives the count"**

Comment: I have made a rank histogram python function available for anyone to use. github: https://github.com/oliverangelil/rankhistogram pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rank-histogram/0.1

Comment: Old question, but for completeness I'd like to add that there is now also a `rank_histogram` function in the [`xskillscore-package`](https://xskillscore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/xskillscore.rank_histogram.html), which provides metrics for verifying forecasts when working with `xarrays` in Python. The output can be plotted as a histogram using `matplotlib.pyplot.barplot()` and adjusting the keywords as you like.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in [this pdf](http://test.scs.fsu.edu/presentations/wkshp_Mar2006allgood_rev.pdf):

> When two or more forecasts have same value (most commonly 0), random selection is made for which bin receives the count.

The formal source can be found in [this pdf](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/people/tom.hamill/sref2.pdf).

Also, the function `verifRankHist()` from the R package [ensembleBMA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ensembleBMA/index.html), does this job.

Comment: +1, thanks for clarifying your post & adding a valuable answer.